# rout registration breaks when I change the url in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

The following rout registration works for my asp.net MVC application

```
    routes.MapRoute("TrackingChannels", "TrackingChannels/{action}",
        new { controller = "TrackingChannels", action = "Index" });
```

When I **change** it to catch this url,

I get `resource not found` error

> for localhost:85\dis\TrackingChannels

```
        routes.MapRoute("TrackingChannels", "Dis/TrackingChannels/{action}",
            new { controller = "TrackingChannels", action = "Index" });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Setting up a project template with what you have gives me no problems.  I can navigate to `/dis/trackingchannels` and the index view is located successfully.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're using backslashes instead of forwardslashes but I can't reproduce that here (in fact, all of my browsers either change backslashes to forwardslashes or give me an error dialog.).  Would you like me to post details of what's working for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I need to go out so I'll post this now as I don't know how long I'll be.

I setup a default MVC 3 project and changed the routing to match your case.

Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "TrackingChannels", 
        "Dis/TrackingChannels/{action}", 
        new { controller = "TrackingChannels", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Added a `TrackingChannelsController`:

```
public class TrackingChannelsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I deliberately added the `Test` action to see if `/dis/trackingchannels/{action}` would also work.  Then I added a couple of views which resulted in the following project structure:

[image: Project setup]

Finally, here's the results of specifying the URLs in the browser:

First with `/dis/trackingchannels`:

[image: TrackingChannels Index]

Second with `/dis/trackingchannels/test`:

[image: TrackingChannels Test]

The only thing I can say without seeing your project is to double check the URL is matching the correct route.  To do that you can use [Phil Haack's RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx).